# 301 redirect - with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=philosophie
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.ch/buero.html [R=301,L]
```

I want to redirect

/index.php?page=geschaeftsleitung to    /buero.html

but with my rule I get http://www.example.ch/buero.html?page=philosophie

How can I rewrite the rule so that I didn't get ?page=philosophie in the end of the new link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=philosophie
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.ch/buero.html? [R=301,L]
```

"?" at the end of the rewrite target removes the query string.